# How to deploy node app with python script that require pip packages using node.js child_process

Tags: python, node.js, pip, mern, child-process

I created a MERN app that has a python script that uses child_process to communicate with node.js. I'm stuck on installing pip packages that are within the python script when I deploy my node app on render.com. How do I install the pip packages on my node app? I create a requirements.txt file that has a list of all the pip packages required. I run npm run build on this package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "dev": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^2.1.0",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.54.0",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^7.0.3",
    "nodemailer": "^6.9.3",
    "openai": "^3.2.1",
    "stripe": "^12.9.0",
    "validator": "^13.9.0"
  }
}
```

Any advice would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

I tried npm run build && pip i *package names*

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.